# Global Modal with Vue 3 + Bootstrap + Pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, pinia

I have made a ModalComponent.vue file which I want to reuse everywhere. The modal has slots for the title, body and footer. It has a standard close modal button, which works fine.

I want to have another button next to it, to do calls to my Pinia stores.

So for example, I have a table with items. I want to delete one item. I click the trash can icon and the modal opens (this works for the specific item).

Inside the modal, I have the confirm button which can be different for every table (Save, Continue, Delete etc).

So now, I want the specific item to be deleted. Click the button in the component, the store is called and correctly removes the item (I see it happening in the table underneath the backdrop).

Now I want the modal to close. So after the store call, I want the modal to close. I have tried everything under the sun, but it is not closing.

I tried to put dataModal.value to false, nothing happens or just the backdrop remains. I tried emitting an event from the Pinia store, nothing. No error, no console.logs..

How can I make this happen?

Here is my ModalComponent.vue:

```
    <template>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" ref="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                <slot name="title"></slot>
              </h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" @click="hideModal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <slot name="body"></slot>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <Button :content='$t("buttons.cancel")' variant="btn-danger" icon="x-lg" :circle="false" @click="hideModal" />
              <slot name="button"></slot> // here is where the dynamic button will be placed
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script setup>
    import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';
    import Button from '@/components/Buttons/Button.vue';
    import { watchEffect, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
    
    const props = defineProps({
      showModal: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      }
    });
    
    const modalInstance = ref(null);
    
    onMounted(() => {
      modalInstance.value = new Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), {
        target: "#myModal",
        backdrop: "static"
      });
    });
    
    watchEffect(() => {
      if (props.showModal === true && modalInstance.value) {
        modalInstance.value.show();
      }
    });
    
    const emit = defineEmits('close-modal');
    
    function hideModal() {
      if (modalInstance.value) {
        modalInstance.value.hide();
        emit('close-modal');
      }
    }
    
    </script>
```

Here is the component that loads in the component and the table:

```
<template>

    <modal-component @close-modal="dataModal = false" :showModal="dataModal" @item-deleted="dataModal = false">
      <template v-slot:title>
        {{ $t('itemTitle') }}
      </template>
      <template v-slot:body>
        {{ $t('itemBody') }}
      </template>
      <template v-slot:button>
        <Button :content='$t("buttons.delete")' variant="btn-secondary" icon="trash-fill" :circle="false" @click="onDelete" />
      </template>
    </modal-component>

    <Table />
</template>

<script setup>

import Button from '@/components/Buttons/Button.vue'

import ModalComponent from '@/components/ModalComponent'

import { computed, ref, watch, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useItemsStore } from '@/stores/store-items'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'


const { getItems, addItems, removeItems, updateItems } = useItemsStore()

const { isLoading, items } = storeToRefs(useItemsStore())

getItems()

const dataModal = ref(false)

function onDelete(){
  removeItems(itemToBeDeleted.id) // <-- call to the store
  getItems(); 
}

</script>
```

And here is my Pinia store file:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { apiClient } from "@/services/api-client";
import mitt from 'mitt'

const emitter = mitt()


export const useItemsStore = defineStore('ItemsStore', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            items: [],
            isLoading: false
        }
    },
 
    actions: {
        
        async removeItems(id) {
            this.isLoading = true;
            
            return apiClient.RemoveItem({id:id})
                .then(response => {
                    // if(!hasError(dispatch, commit, response)){
                        let index = 0;
                        for(let i=0; i < this.items.length; i++){
                            if(this.items[i].id === id){
                                index = i;
                            }   
                        }
                    
                        this.items.splice(index, 1);
                        this.isLoading = false;

                        emitter.emit('item-deleted')

                        return response.succes
                    // }
                    //
                    // return false;
                })
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after another 16 hours of slowly going insane, here is my not so clean but working solution. This code shows and hides the Bootstrap 5 modal with transitions and the backdrop:

ModalComponent.vue:

```
<template>
  <div :id="id" class="modal fade" ref="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
            <slot name="title"></slot>
          </h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" @click="hideModal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <slot name="body"></slot>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <Button :content='$t("buttons.cancel")' variant="btn-danger" icon="x-lg" :circle="false" @click="hideModal" />
          <slot name="button"></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';
import Button from '@/components/Buttons/Button.vue';
import { watchEffect, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  id: {
    type: String
  }
});

const modalInstance = ref(null);

const emit = defineEmits(['get-modal'])

onMounted(() => {
  modalInstance.value = new Modal(document.getElementById(props.id), {
    target: props.id,
    backdrop: "static",
  });

  emit('get-modal', modalInstance.value)
});



function hideModal() {
  if (modalInstance.value) {
    modalInstance.value.hide();
  }
}

</script>
```

The component that calls the modal component:

```
<template>

    <modal-component @get-modal="modalGetted" :id="'deleteItemmodal'">
      <template v-slot:title>
        {{ $t('ModalTitle') }}
      </template>
      <template v-slot:body>
        {{ $t('ModalBody') }}
      </template>
      <template v-slot:button>
        <Button :content='$t("buttons.delete")' variant="btn-secondary" icon="trash-fill" :circle="false" @click="onDelete" />
      </template>
    </modal-component>
    
</template>

<script setup>
import Button from '@/components/Buttons/Button.vue'
import ModalComponent from '@/components/ModalComponent'


const { isLoading, items } = storeToRefs(useItemsStore())


let modalInstance = ref(null)

function modalGetted(modal) {
  modalInstance = modal // set the modal
}

function onShowDeleteModal(item) {
  itemToBeDeleted = item
  modalInstance.show() //show the modal
}


function onDelete(){
  removeItems(itemToBeDeleted.id)
  modalInstance.hide() // hide the modal
  getItems();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Does data-modal control the display of your modal if yes then put:

> dataModal.value = false

after the call of your functions 'removeItems' or even after 'getItems' in your function 'onDelete'.

If this is not the case create a ref 'showModal' in your script and use 'v-show' or 'v-if' to control the visibility of your modal

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried that (see original question), this also works (item gets removed) but the backdrop of the modal is still there:

function onDelete(){
  removeItems(itemToBeDeleted.id)
  dataModal.value = false; // backdrop is still there
  getItems();
}

Comment: $('.modal-backdrop').remove()

$(document.body).removeClass("modal-open");

Add one of this after getItems if this is just the backdrop maybe

Comment: In vue script it would be :
document.getElementById('yourModal').classList.remove('modal-backdrop');
  document.getElementsByName('body').item(0).classList.remove('modal-open');

Comment: Last but not least, just remove the "fade" class, it is a bootstrap bug

Comment: Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

Comment: Your body can't be null, have you tried to remove the fade class ?

Comment: Its working but I feel like this is a very ugly solution, no offense.. All the closing of the modal functionality is in the data-bs-dismiss attribute, why is there no nice javascript for closing the modal?

Comment: document.getElementById('yourModal').classList.remove('modal-backdrop'); document.getElementsByName('body').item(0).classList.remove('modal-open');

You can still try that it is the cleanest solution, you just have to adapt it to your project. But this is a bug of B4 and removing the fade class isn't a dirty solution

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 5 & I understand that it maybe is a nice solution in your perception but I would like to maybe watch for changes in the ModalComponent, kill the modal instance or emit an event in the store... not just manipulate the DOM like its 2003....